# MinGW Compile Error - '__off64_t' does not name a type

Tags: c++, mingw

I just reinstalled MinGW and the Codelite IDE on my Windows PC, however I'm now unable to compile/build a project.

It is odd because every time I change a setting or make a new project, I am able to run it once, then it stops working.

I've already tried reinstalling MinGW...

[image]

Comment: Do you mind replacing the picture by actual text?

Comment: Sorry, the IDE I am using does not let you copy the build text.

Comment: "...does not let you copy the build text." Yes it does. Click **Select all** in the **Build** output tab, then **Copy**. Then paste in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug of gcc that occurs when applying c++11 or newer standards, ie adding parameter "-std=c++11" or "-std=c++0x". 
I fixed it by adding "#include "io.h"" in the file stdio.h.

you can go to your include path: "c:/mingw/include" and edit the "stdio.h".

`/*
     * stdio.h
     *
     * Definitions of types and prototypes of functions for operations on
     * standard input and standard output streams.
     *
     * $Id: stdio.h,v 8863016e809f 2018/12/04 19:00:29 keith $
     *
     * Written by Colin Peters 
     * Copyright (C) 1997-2005, 2007-2010, 2014-2018, MinGW.org Project.
     *
     *
     * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
     * copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
     * to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
     * the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
     * and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
     * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
     *
     * The above copyright notice, this permission notice, and the following
     * disclaimer shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of
     * the Software.
     *
     * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
     * OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
     * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
     * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
     * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
     * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OF OR OTHER
     * DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
     *
     * NOTE: The file manipulation functions provided by Microsoft seem to
     * work with either slash (/) or backslash () as the directory separator;
     * (this is consistent with Microsoft's own documentation, on MSDN).
     *
     */
    #include     //include at here
    #ifndef _STDIO_H
    #pragma GCC system_header`

```
/* When including <wchar.h>, some of the definitions and declarations
 * which are nominally provided in <stdio.h> must be duplicated.  Rather
 * than require duplicated maintenance effort, we provide for partial
 * inclusion of <stdio.h> by <wchar.h>; only when not included in
 * this partial fashion...
 */
```

If there is any problems or a better solution, i would appreciate your feedback very gladly.